# Convert dataframe to numpy matrix where indexes stored in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe that looks like so

```
    time                    usd    hour  day
0    2015-08-30 07:56:28    1.17    7    0
1    2015-08-30 08:56:28    1.27    8    0
2    2015-08-30 09:56:28    1.28    9    0
3    2015-08-30 10:56:28    1.29    10    0
4    2015-08-30 11:56:28    1.29    11    0
14591   2017-04-30 23:53:46 9.28    23  609
```

Given this how would I go about building a numpy 2d matrix with hour being one axis day being the other axis and then usd being the value stored in the matrix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        time=pd.date_range('2015-08-30', periods=14000, freq='H'),
        usd=(np.random.randn(14000) / 100 + 1.0005).cumprod()
    ))
```

Then we can set the index with the `date` and `hour` of `df.time` column and `unstack`.  We take the `values` of this result in order to access the numpy array.

```
a = df.set_index([df.time.dt.date, df.time.dt.hour]).usd.unstack().values
```

Answer (score 4):

I would do a pivot_table and leave the data as a pandas DataFrame but the conversion to a numpy array is trivial if you don't want labels.

```
import pandas as pd
data = <data>
data.pivot_table(values = 'usd', index = 'hour', columns = 'day').values
```

Edit: Thank you @pyRSquared for the "Value"able tip.  (changed np.array(data) to df...values)

Comment: thanks.  I had multiple correct answers but this one was first.

Comment: @TommieJones I don't mind you choosing whatever answer you find is appropriate to you.. However, just keeping the record straight, my answer came two minutes prior to this one.

Comment: @piRSquared and mine came 5 minutes prior to yours :)

Comment: @mischi it sure did :-)

Comment: I don't mind if you switch the answer.  I know @piRSquared and someone who deleted their answer were first.  Plus stack() and unstack() are more powerful tools because pivot_table is limited to one column for values and one for the index where stack and unstack are unlimited (till N-1 colums/rows).  Thanks for the upvotes though.

Comment: @Back2Basics I'm all for you keeping the accepted answer :-)  Its just little things like choosing an answer based on timing only to get the timing wrong.  I can let my compulsions get the best of me sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `pivot` functionality of `pandas`, as described [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html#reshaping-by-pivoting-dataframe-objects). You will get `NaN` values for `usd`, when there is no value for the `day` or `hour`.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'usd': [1.17, 1.27, 1.28, 1.29, 1.29, 9.28], 'hour': [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 23], 'day': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 609]})

In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
   day  hour   usd
0    0     7  1.17
1    0     8  1.27
2    0     9  1.28
3    0    10  1.29
4    0    11  1.29
5  609    23  9.28

In [4]: df.pivot(index='hour', columns='day', values='usd')
Out[4]: 
day    0     609
hour            
7     1.17   NaN
8     1.27   NaN
9     1.28   NaN
10    1.29   NaN
11    1.29   NaN
23     NaN  9.28
```